# Google apps scripts: How to properly work with comma separated spreadsheet values converted to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet in which column 1 includes source file IDs; each cell contains only one ID. In column 2, there are destination file IDs where a single cell contains multiple IDs separated by a comma. I have a script that gets these values and does other things. Here is a snippet that includes all manipulations done to the variables in question:

```
// Retrieve the source and destination IDs from spreadsheet
  var toFileIds = myFile.getRange(2,2,key.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();               // Get the destination file IDs from myFile
  var sourceFileIds = myFile.getRange(2,1,key.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();           // Get the source file IDs from myFile

// Write-out the global vars 
  var stringtoFileIds = JSON.stringify(toFileIds);                                       // Convert to string as required by PropertiesService
  var stringsourceFileIds = JSON.stringify(sourceFileIds);                               // Convert to string as required by PropertiesService
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('toFileIds', stringtoFileIds);    
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('sourceFileIds', stringsourceFileIds);
```

I have a second script that looks at a source file and finds the corresponding destination files identified above:

```
// Read-in global vars
  toFileIds = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('toFileIds');
  sourceFileIds = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('sourceFileIds');
  toFileIds = JSON.parse(toFileIds);
  sourceFileIds = JSON.parse(sourceFileIds);

// Retrieve the destination file IDs  
  var ArrPos = sourceFileIds.indexOf('activeFile'); // Find the position of the active file name within the stored arr   
  var destFileIds = destFileIds[ArrPos]; // Use that position to find the destination files

  var destFileIds = destFileIds.toString().split(","); // Do this so that each comma separated ID is its own element in arr


// Mark if there are no destination files  
  if (destFileIds == undefined) {
    var destFileIds = "no";
  }  

// Cache the var
  cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  cache.put("destFileIds", JSON.stringify(destFileIds), 400);
```

Finally, I have a third script that includes an error checking snippet. It's here that the issue occurs:

```
if (destFileIds != "no") {
  for (var i = 0; i <= destFileIds.length -1; i++) {
    try {
      DriveApp.getFileById(destFileIds[i]); 
    } catch (e) {
      //Logger.log(e.message);
      throw 'At least one of the destination files does not exist.';
    }
  }
}
```

For this final code snippet, I would expect an error message to appear only if an ID in the array does not exit. When all elements of `destFileIds` exist, this snippet works for the first element, but then throws the above defined error for the second element of the array and subsequently quits. I'm 100% sure that all the file IDs are correct. I manually checked this by placing them in the URL. I also manually defined an array with these IDs and the code ran fine, i.e. this runs as expected:

```
var destFileIds = ["myID1", "myID2", "myID3"]; // Where these are replaced with real IDs

if (destFileIds != "no") {
  for (var i = 0; i <= destFileIds.length -1; i++) {
    try {
      DriveApp.getFileById(destFileIds[i]);
    } catch (e) {
      //Logger.log(e.message);
      throw 'No updates were made because all of the related (copy to) templates do not appear to exist.';
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas about why the second element may not be read the same as the first element of `destFileIds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple error. The destination files within my spreadsheet cells weren’t solely separated by a comma. They were separated by a comma followed by a space. I changed `var destFileIds = destFileIds.toString().split(",")` to `var destFileIds = destFileIds.toString().split(", ")`. This accommodates the spaces and eliminates my problem.

Hopefully this prevents someone else from wasting as much time as I did on this….

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to change the locale of the whole document with:

1. Manually: `File` -> `Spreadsheet` -> settings and checking the Locale setting.
2. By Scripting:

```
 // Get reference to the whole document
 var newDocument = SpreadsheetApp.create(documentName);

 // Change the locale
 newDocument.setSpreadsheetLocale('es');
```